# C# HTTP request with proxy

Tags: c#, http, proxy

*I'm trying to make an HTTP request with a proxy list.
I'm not really sure where to start as I couldn't find anything related to web clients with proxies. I'm new to C# so might be missing something.
My goal at the end of the day is to loop through a proxy list and use each one for a HTTP request. If anyone could point me in the right direction I would be very grateful.*

```
public void makeRequest(string password, string email, string firstName, string lastName) {
        var cookieJar = new CookieContainer();
        CookieAwareWebClient client = new CookieAwareWebClient(cookieJar);
        string response = client.DownloadString("http://example.com");

        string token = Regex.Match(response, "authenticity_token.+?value=\"(.+?)\"").Groups[1].Value;
        string postData =
            string.Format("authenticity_token={0}&signup_ui_metrics=%7B%22rf%22%3A%7B%22a329c5b5bc6c102ef9c1d63f316f58ac8fb4532446a1e4c83a11d61dac0f0d88%22%3A128%2C%22ee55fdfa42bd4572ff3a3690c7d2e50796a0b4d842b51b2130eb6fa7818ca273%22%3A-1%2C%22a52e852b39ea535cd0dfdc5f0b421766719588a7600ffc992fc224f920e92a81%22%3A158%2C%22fdd9b9308177fabcd24ea3310770605522530c56e0c3884906198e2a81c793f7%22%3A170%7D%2C%22s%22%3A%22oVgQBK7u_ZBbokRa-9tVVDtYQIBFf5ndDt-8Juqa-0i4-X5KwVsPwEUYqDkfB24YH5hsr_tmqPm6769FZvg-eYDljhWCc3tvyTno6Ts_QeAFb8mMS-13wvcxJkrKTUNyb5ac_-kzalx_WKsR0BD-Q4gM9YQ52IYwu4X0Sj2qubjIpjygiZH-vZgMJTkwQZP4jK8q4LoC37liW1gbSM4kv9NNK5g-c-2VR79yDC92moRaEqS9XOpzP1zYEfDdGLZDLCNW0C8E8qaz_b-l1M5mV04ih7WHbRE5QjV1bZohkiFF5Xa2nteIoSCHnZjD41JA0M9wntp66gLjuZUrBJLX0QAAAV0WYV14%22%7D&m_metrics=thMqEh0A8SkAthM9EhMA9ykAthNZEhwA%2FSkAthNsEhMAByoAthOIEhwAGioAthObEhMALCoAwRObEgsAMCoAwRO4Eh0APCoAwRPLEhMARioAwRPnEhwATioAwRP6EhMAVioAwRMWExwAXCoAthMWEwsAXioAthMpExMAYioAthNGEx0AbioAwRNGEwsAmioAwRNZExMAsioA0BNZEw8AwCoA0BN1ExwAwSoA0BOIExMAzyoA%3AuQQJALkEtg0AXBQPDB4AUicA&d_metrics=&user%5Bname%5D=" + firstName + "+" + lastName + "&user%5Bemail%5D=" + email + "&user%5Buser_password%5D=" + password + "&user%5Buse_cookie_personalization%5D=1&asked_cookie_personalization_setting=1&ad_ref=&user%5Bdiscoverable_by_email%5D=1&asked_discoverable_by_email=1&user%5Bdiscoverable_by_mobile_phone%5D=1&asked_discoverable_by_mobile_phone=1", token);
        client.Method = "POST";
        response = client.UploadString("http://example.com/create", postData);
    }
```

Any help related to what i'm asking again would be amazing.